# Using public void decide ()?

Tags: java

I made a program that accepts numbers from the user.

Sample of my program:

```
   int strength, health, luck;

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Welcome to Yertle's Quest");    

      String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of your character");

       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter strength (1-10): ");
      strength = in.nextInt();

     System.out.println("Enter health (1-10): ");      
      health = in.nextInt();

     System.out.println("Enter luck (1-10): ");      
      luck = in.nextInt();
```

My problem is this:
The user is only able to give 15 points. If he puts more than 10 points to each stats (strength,health,luck), the default value will be assign to each stats -which is 5. And if the total points on each stats(strength,health,luck) is more than 15, the default value will be assigned to each stats.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: "How to assign default value to each stats(which is 5)" if the total points on each stats(strength,health,luck) is more than 15 and If he puts more than 10 points to each stats (strength,health,luck), default value will be assign to each stats which is 5

Comment: Please work on improving the clarity of your question.

Comment: if (health + strength + luck > 15) { health = 5; strength = 5; luck = 5;}

Comment: Im not good in english, Im so sorry

Answer (score 0):

Given I understand the question correctly:

```
if ( luck + health + strength > 15) {
    luck = 5;
    health = 5;
    strength = 5;
}
if (luck > 10) { luck = 5; }
// same for the other attributes
```

Comment: now my problem is if the user put number correctly it will print "Congrats" but if it is more that 15pts. it will print "You have given your character too many points! Default values have been assigned: Character, strength: 5, health: 5, luck: 5"
 
Using public void decide ()??? how??

Comment: yeah, Im almost done, but I dont know what is this public void decide() all about.. please help me.

Comment: I think it will decide if the user put number correctly it will print congratz if not, it will set the stats to default value which is 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strength > 10)
{
 defaultToFive(strength);
}

if(health > 10)
{
 defaultToFive(health);
}

if(luck > 10)
{
 defaultToFive(luck);
}

if((strength + health + luck) > 15)
{
 defaultToFive(strength);
 defaultToFive(health);
 defaultToFive(luck);
}

private void defaultToFive(int stat)
{
 stat=5;
}
```

Comment: now my problem is if the user put number correctly it will print "Congrats" but if it is more that 15pts. it will print "You have given your character too many points! Default values
have been assigned:
Character, strength: 5, health: 5, luck: 5"

Comment: @NEWBIE You need to put in a little effort here, use an else statement in the if(blahh>10){...} else "Congrats"  I'll leave it to you to figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple `if` statements:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class CheckLuck {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);int strength,health,luck;
 System.out.println("Enter strength (1-10): ");
 strength = in.nextInt();

   if(strength>10)    /* chech for each value, should not be >10 */
   strength=5;

 System.out.println("Enter health (1-10): ");
 health = in.nextInt();
   if(health>10)
   health=5;

 System.out.println("Enter luck (1-10): ");
 luck = in.nextInt();

   if(luck>10)
      luck=5;


 if(strength+health+luck>15)   /* If sum  is >15 assign 5 to each value */
  strength=health=luck=5;

 }

}
```

**UPDATE :                 USING public void decide()**

(sorry if this sounds funny)

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class TestDecide {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);int strength,health,luck;
System.out.println("Enter strength (1-10): ");
strength = in.nextInt();

if(strength>10)
strength=5;

 System.out.println("Enter health (1-10): ");
 health = in.nextInt();

 if(health>10)
 health=5;

 System.out.println("Enter luck (1-10): ");
 luck = in.nextInt();
  if(luck>10)
      luck=5;

if(strength+health+luck>15)
{
strength=health=luck=5;
decide();
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Congrats!!!!!!!!!!!! for your scores");



}

}
public static void decide()
{
System.out.println("You have given your character too many points! Default values have been assigned: Character, strength: 5, health: 5, luck: 5");


}

}
```

Comment: now my problem is if the user put number correctly it will print "Congrats" but if it is more that 15pts. it will print "You have given your character too many points! Default values have been assigned: Character, strength: 5, health: 5, luck: 5"
 
Using public void decide ()??? how??

Comment: how about,, if strength is more that 10, health and luck will automatically turn to 5, How sir????